# Typeform api, change variables names in results

Tags: php, typeform

I am using typeform as a tool to get feedback and contact infos.
By using the api, I get results from my survey with the following format  :

```
                [answers] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [field] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [id] => XdLvktpeAVmc
                                        [type] => short_text
                                        [ref] => 88e1657e-516b-4219-8086-52ba80e55eb0
                                    )

                                [type] => text
                                [text] => Test1
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [field] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [id] => QLYWXINAKoeS
                                        [type] => number
                                        [ref] => c431bf84-7305-4171-a659-67191b797651
                                    )

                                [type] => number
                                [number] => 111111111
                            )

                        [2] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [field] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [id] => wRSL0qJ7BSWH
                                        [type] => email
                                        [ref] => 719312ce-9ae9-4a45-9b9f-fdfaf3d23dc1
                                    )

                                [type] => email
                                [email] => Test1@email.com
                            )

                    )

                [hidden] => stdClass Object
                    (
                    )

                [calculated] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [score] => 0
                    )

            )
```

Is it possible to change the name of the variables (text, number, email) ? I've tried using hidden fields but it's not the feature to use.

Thanks

Comment: In that exemple https://developer.typeform.com/responses/example-response/ they managed to set the "ref" field, but there is no apparent option to modify it in the typeform interface

Comment: Hi Phelineg,

`text`, `number`, `email` you are referring to are the type of a field.
If you want to change the type of field you can do it using the Create API update method.

`ref` is indeed your `variable name` and it won't change.

  [1]: https://developer.typeform.com/create/reference/update-form-patch/

Comment: Thank you for your answer Nicolas ! I'll look at the update method